# SQL Trigger after insert update

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

What is wrong with this code.

If i type like this

```
Declare tmp as CURSOR FOR
Select i.ID from Inserted
OPEN tmp
```

Or if i type

```
Declare tmp as CURSOR FOR
Select i.ID from Deleted
OPEN tmp
```

Works like a charm but

Is there any way i can write something like this

```
if @operation <> 3

set @tmp = 'SELECT i.id FROM inserted i '

 else

 set @tmp =' SELECT i.id FROM deleted i '

 DECLARE tmpUpit CURSOR FOR 
@tmp
 OPEN tmpUpit
```

Edit :

```
 CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[ax_Triger] ON [dbo].[extraTable]  
 FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
 --Capture the Operation (Inserted, Deleted Or Updated)

    DECLARE @operation int
    DECLARE @Count AS INT

    SET @operation = 1

    SELECT @Count = COUNT(*)
    FROM   DELETED

    IF @Count > 0
      BEGIN
          SET @operation = 3

          SELECT @Count = COUNT(*)
          FROM   INSERTED

          IF @Count > 0
            SET @operation = 2
      END
DECLARE tmpUpit CURSOR FOR 
SELECT i.id FROM inserted i
OPEN tmpUpit 
FETCH NEXT FROM tmpUpit
into @ID WHILE @@fetch_status = 0 

begin  If Not exists 
 (SELECT * FROM mytable
 where (Operation=3 OR (Operation=1 AND ID=@ID)) AND Status = 0 AND Tablename ='extraTable')

 begin  INSERT INTO 
 mytable  ([Field1], [Field2], 
 [ID], [Tablename], [Operation], [Time12], [Status]) 
 VALUES (@Field1, @Field2, @ID, 'extraTable',  @operation,GETDATE(),0) 

 DELETE FROM mytable
 WHERE [Field1]=@Field1 And [Field2]=@Field2 And [ID]=@ID And [Tablename]='extraTable' 
 AND [Operation] = 4 AND [Status] = 0 
 End 
 FETCH NEXT FROM tmpUpit into @ID 
 End CLOSE tmpUpit DEALLOCATE tmpUpit end
```

i need to insert the value from one table to another depending about the status Inserted/updated/deleted

Comment: Why are you wanting a cursor in the first place? They are horribly inefficient. The approach you are trying will not work because you have crossed over into dynamic sql land. If you can post some details about what your trigger is trying to do we can help you find a set based approach that doesn't need a cursor.

Comment: @SeanLange i just hit edit ..This is my first trigger

Comment: @myString, you can declare it conditionally, you can even pass cursor variable as a parameter to SP. You don't need dynamic sql for it. But somehow I assume you need `FULL JOIN`.

Comment: There is no circumstance where you want to put a cursor in a  trigger. Never. This is easily done in a set-based fashion and will be fewer lines of code too.

Comment: There is absolutely no need for a cursor here at all. This is two basic statements, an insert and a delete. I can't really offer much here though because you didn't provide the whole trigger. You have some additional scalar values outside of your cursor. Scalar values in a cursor are a huge red flag that the contents are not set based and can't handle multiple row operations. Post the ddl for mytable and whatever table this trigger is attached to and I can help you sort this out.

Comment: @SeanLange im glad you want to help me out .. Here it is sir
http://pastebin.com/PcQUNU65

Comment: How about myRequests and Towns? Kind of hard to test any code doing any inserts without any of the tables involved.

Comment: @SeanLange here is entire test table i made http://pastebin.com/0B7SkTE6

Comment: This is a train wreck. You have now posted tables that don't even come close to the trigger code you posted.

Comment: I cant put those tables in public so i'm trying to make something close to my problem.

Comment: Well you should at least make the columns match your trigger code. This is about 10 times harder than it should be. I think I can cobble something together but you are going to have to rework it quite a bit since who knows what columns are what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely untested since the table structures posted did not match the posted trigger code. This should at least demonstrate how you can rethink about this as set based logic instead of row by agonizing row.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger212] ON [dbo].[Towns]  
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @operation int
    DECLARE @Variable1 nvarchar(8) = 'Woof'
    DECLARE @Variable2 nvarchar(4) = 'Foof'

    --Capture the Operation (Inserted, Deleted Or Updated) 
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
        SET @operation = 1 --Insert
    ELSE
        IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
            SET @operation = 2 --update
        ELSE
            SET @operation = 3 -- DELETE

    INSERT Requests
    (
        Field1
        , Field2
        , ID
        , TableName
        , Operation
        , TimeU
        , Status
    )
    SELECT 'Woof'
        , 'Foof'
        , i.ID
        , 'Towns'
        , @operation
        , GETDATE()
        , 0
    FROM inserted i
    LEFT JOIN Requests r on r.ID = i.ID
        AND r.Operation = 3
            OR (r.Operation = 1 and r.ID = i.ID)
        AND r.Status = 0
        AND r.TableName = 'Towns'
    WHERE r.ID IS NULL

    DELETE r
    FROM Requests r
    JOIN inserted i on i.Field1 = r.Field1
        AND i.Field2 = r.Field2
        AND i.ID = r.ID
        AND i.Operation <> @operation
    WHERE r.TableName = 'Towns'
        AND r.Status = 0   
END
```

In general I think triggers should be avoided but they have their place. When triggers are appropriate I am generally not a big fan of doing all three operations. Over time it gets really messy because invariably you need to do different logic for the different operations. Splitting them into three triggers makes this eventuality a lot less painful for maintenance.